# Conditional auth-provider in auth-manager

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have security configuration via xml. I've added an extra provider. So it looks like this:

```
<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="first" />
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="second">
    </sec:authentication-provider>
</sec:authentication-manager>
```

I would like to either use both providers or just one, based on an entry in an `app.properties` file. Is it even possible ?

Comment: Maybe you can create an authentication provider wrapper that depends on the two and do the work based on the properties ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to have each `AuthenticationProvider` answer for itself. There is a `supports` method that you can implement or there is the option of returning `null` from `authenticate`, which indicates that this `AuthenticationProvider` is abstaining.

### Overriding `supports`

```
public class FirstAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Value("${myapp.security.usefirst}") boolean useFirst;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return useFirst && anyOtherTestingNecessary;
    }
}
```

### `AuthenticationProvider` abstains

```
public class SecondAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Value("${myapp.security.usefirst}") boolean useFirst;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
        if ( useFirst ) {
            return null; // abstain
        }

        // ... rest of authentication strategy
    }
```

}

If you are using Spring 4 or higher, then you can use the `@Conditional` annotation to wire each provider conditionally based on your property, though based on your question, I'll forgo that example.

You can, of course, as suggested in a comment, create a wrapper `AuthenticationProvider`, though this can cause some heartburn depending on your wiring strategy. Also, it is duplicating a little bit of the work that `ProviderManager` is already intended to do.

Comment: My first provider is `DaoAuthenticationProvider ` (that's fine) but my second is `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider ` which is final. What are my options in that situation ?

Comment: I realize that you posted xml config, however if Java config is an option, it is quite a bit more powerful. In that case, you can conditionally add them in your `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder impl)` method. See the docs for some examples, https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authentication-jdbc.

Comment: The other option, of course, is to create a wrapper `AuthenticationProvider` that delegates. The only reason I shy away from that is something that may not apply to you today, which is component scanning. If you are doing strictly xml wiring, then it shouldn't be a problem.